# How to reject a field from bean for validation when binding?

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, annotations, hibernate-validator

I have three fields **`department_Id,department_Name,department_location`** in **`departmentForm`** act as a model object in this model form.

I have use **annotation** to validate the fields. Now, I want to only use two fields in different jsp page say **`create.jsp`** and one field in different jsp page say **`getDepartmentById`**.

When I press submit button of **`create.jsp`**, validation is happening but after providing correct information its not submitted cause in this page.

I **haven't give one field `department_Id`** which is auto generated by my DAO layer. So, please help me, how to reject this value to execute my `create.jsp` page for successfully creating department in database.

When I printed the **`BindingResult`** object, it shown as follow:

```
Field error in object 'departmentForm' on field 'departmentId': rejected value [null]; 
codes [NotEmpty.departmentForm.departmentId,NotEmpty.departmentId,NotEmpty.java.lang.String,NotEmpty]; 
arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: 
codes [departmentForm.departmentId,departmentId]; arguments []; 
default message [departmentId],org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message},
[Ljava.lang.Class;@4fc4a198,[Ljava.lang.Class;@764d2b11]; 
default message [may not be empty]`
```

This is how I coded in controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createDepartment", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createEmployee(@Valid DepartmentForm departmentForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, DepartmentForm> model)
        throws Exception {

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(bindingResult);
        bindingResult.reject(departmentForm.getDepartmentId());
        return "departmentForm";
    }
    System.out.println("mr ankur jadiy");

    model.put("departmentForm", departmentForm);
    departmentForm.setUpdateStatus('A');
    if (departmentForm.getUpdateStatus() == 'A') {
        departmentServiceImpl
            .actionDecider(convertDeptFormToDeptBO(departmentForm));

    }
    return "Success";
}
```

my `DepartmentForm` code is as follow:

```
package com.nousinfo.tutorial.model;

import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

public class DepartmentForm {

    @NotEmpty
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20,message="")
    private String departmentId;
    @NotEmpty
    private String departmentName;

    private String departmentLocation;

    private Character updateStatus;
    public String getDepartmentId() {
        return departmentId;
    }

    public void setDepartmentId(String departmentId) {
        this.departmentId = departmentId;
    }

    public String getDepartmentName() {
        return departmentName;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String departmentName) {
        this.departmentName = departmentName;
    }

    public String getDepartmentLocation() {
        return departmentLocation;
    }

    public void setDepartmentLocation(String departmentLocation) {
        this.departmentLocation = departmentLocation;
    }

    public Character getUpdateStatus() {
        return updateStatus;
    }

    public void setUpdateStatus(Character updateStatus) {
        this.updateStatus = updateStatus;
    }
}
```

and my `create.jsp` is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/input-1.0" prefix="input"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Create Department</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"></link>
</head>

<body>

    <table width="1254" height="74" border="0" align="center">

        <tr>
            <td width="300" height="68" align="center" bgcolor="#99CCFF"><h2>
                    <span class="style1">Employee Details </span>
                </h2></td>
            <td width="100" height="68" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><img
                src="./image/emps.jpg" width="190" height="92" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <p>
        <br />
    </p>
    <hr size="1" width="786">
    <form:form id="form" method="post" action="/EmployeeWebSpring/departmentController/createDepartment"
        modelAttribute="departmentForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <form:hidden path="updateStatus" />
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Department_Name:
                    <font color="red"><form:errors path="departmentName" /></font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="departmentName" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    Department_Location:
                    <font color="red"><form:errors path="departmentLocation" /></font>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="departmentLocation" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <br>
        <br />
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
        <br>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="save" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="method" value="cancel" /></td>
        </tr>

        <hr size="1" width="786">
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Bedwyr Humphreys have a look at this question i m stucking in very minor problem but i m not able to resolve this plz help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error says is that you're missing value for `departmentId`, which is not surprising since you defined it as

```
@NotEmpty
@Size(min = 1, max = 20,message="")
```

You don't really need to validate `departmentId` if it's autogenerated by your code. You probably should remove it from the  `DepartmentForm`, especially since it's not in the form, or at least make it optional.

You can make it mandatory in your business object, but the form backing object should reflect what's in the form.

**update**

If `departmentId` is a database-generated id, you should set it as disallowed in your controller's `InitBinder`:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields(new String[] { "departmentId" }); 
}
```

Comment: is their any way not to reflect or escape the field value in binding object cause i need that field in some other jsp page

Comment: @henrycharles see the edit. Basically you need to disallow that field, and then you don't need the validation anyway afaik.